# Как загрузить фото в настройки плагина WordPress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

У меня есть страница настроек моего плагина, где можно добавить несколько текстовых полей и фото. 
Сейчас ситуация такова, что при выборе файла и нажатии сохранить изменения фото не загружается в настройки и пропадает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    function cases_conf() {
?>
<div class="wrap">
<h2>Кейсы</h2>
<form method="post" action="options.php">
<?php wp_nonce_field('update-options'); ?>

<p>
Добавляйте удаляйте и редактируйте кейсы:<br />
</p>

<table class="form-table" id="op_table">
<tr valign="top">
<th scope="row">Название</th>
<th scope="row">Список</th>
<th scope="row">Результат</th>
<th scope="row">Картинка</th>
<th scope="row">Delete</th>
</tr>
<?php
//Get the options
$header=get_option('cases_header');
$points=get_option('cases_points');
$result=get_option('cases_result');
$img=get_option('cases_img');

for ($i=0;$i<count($header);$i++) {
?>
<tr valign="top" id="row<?php echo $i; ?>">
<td><input type="text" name="cases_header[]" value="<?php echo $header[$i]; ?>" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="cases_points[]" value="<?php echo $points[$i]; ?>" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="cases_result[]" value="<?php echo $result[$i]; ?>" /></td>
<td><input type="file" name="cases_img[]" id="wp_custom_attachment" value="<?php echo $img[$i]; ?>" /></td>
<td><a  href="#" onclick="return case_deleteRow('<?php echo $i; ?>');"><?php echo _e('Delete') ?></a></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>

<a  href="#" onclick="return case_addMore();"><?php echo _e('New') ?></a><br />

<input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
<input type="hidden" name="page_options" value="cases_header,cases_points,cases_result,cases_img" />

<p class="submit">
<input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>" />
</p>

</form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://orenyomtov.com/downloads/plugins_outform.php?plugin=cases"></script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Приложите код, относящийся к настройкам плагина.

Comment: а не пробовал использовать ACF, надежней и большой функционал у него

Comment: @LieutenantJimDangle , Это нужно для решения одной узкой задачи.

Comment: @KAGGDesign , Сделал, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: @иванганенко так ACF глобальное решение ряда задач неважно каких

Comment: @LieutenantJimDangle иногда хочется что бы вещь была как можно проще но выполняла единственную возложенную на нее функцию. Понимаете?)

Comment: А где код обработки полей формы (plugins_outform.php)? Ну, и вообще, так не делают. Есть механизм в WP для сохранения настроек темы или плагина. Хорошее описание здесь: https://wp-kama.ru/id_3773/api-optsiy-nastroek.html

Comment: @KAGGDesign Вы имеете в виду что нужно регистрировать поля или что картинка в войдёт в настройки? А как обработать форму в другом файле? Закинуть его в папку с плагином и он автоматически заинклудиться?

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что есть встроенный функционал, и лучше пользоваться им, а не изобретать велосипед.

Comment: @KAGGDesign допустим я зарегистрирую поля настроек. Смогу ли я добавить картинку к настройкам?

Comment: Конечно. Разницы нет, что сохранять - текст или id изображения.

Comment: @KAGGDesign значит я сейчас выполню регистрацию полей и все красиво оформлю и отпишу

Comment: @KAGGDesign Сделал все как написано. Возник вопрос. Как стандартными функциями ВП создать новые поля не выходя из настроек и как поставить полю тип file?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57111/discussion-between-kagg-design-and--).

Comment: Мне помогла статья которую скинул @KAGGDesign http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874469/wordpress-upload-image-in-admin-options-page